# Switch from animating frames to animating constraints

Tags: ios, animation, uiscrollview, autolayout

I had what seemed a perfectly good animation scheme (animating frame attributes using `UIView animateWithDuration`) until an upgrade to Xcode 6 or iOS 8 (or both) changed everything. I suspect that part of the problem is that I paid scant attention to AutoLayout because the app only supports portrait view.

A picture is worth a thousand words, and a video is worth a million, so a screen capture example of this change in animation can be seen in the following youtube uploads:

[The first example](http://youtu.be/BoR-ZUB1fyA) (iOS 7) graphically shows what I'm trying to achieve, and [the second](http://youtu.be/BoR-ZUB1fyA) shows what happened after I switched to Xcode 6 / iOS 8. Please view if you want to respond:

Here's my current (simplified) code, which is inside a fast enumeration loop iterating over the fetchedResults of a FRC:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.8
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^
     {
         // Starting state *************************************

         thisBar.frame = CGRectMake(20, self.scroller.contentSize.height, 130, 0);
         thisBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

         thisInfoLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, self.scroller.contentSize.height, thisBar.frame.size.width, 30);
         thisTimeLabel.frame = CGRectMake((thisBar.frame.origin.x) + (thisBar.frame.size.width + 35), self.scroller.contentSize.height, 150, 15);

         thisTimeLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
         arrowView.frame = CGRectMake(thisTimeLabel.frame.origin.x - 20, thisTimeLabel.frame.origin.y, 16, 16);

         thisInfoLabel.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];


         // End state *************************************

         thisBar.frame = CGRectMake(20, barY, 130, - barHeight);
         thisBar.backgroundColor = thisBar.endColor;

         thisBar.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
         thisBar.layer.frame = CGRectInset(thisBar.layer.frame, 0.0, 3.0);

         thisBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
         thisBar.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0;
         thisBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f);
         ...
}
```

I've read various possible reasons for this change, but the detail appears to be moot, and apparently the only proper way to fix the problem is to switch from animating the frame attributes of my views and start animating constraints instead.

OK, I accept it. However, as I've looked at quite a few SO posts on the subject for guidance, most seem to be geared toward IB-generated views. My views are code generated, of any number, and of any height, both of which are determined on the fly in code. For added drama, these views are inside a `UIScrollView`.

At this point, it seems my strategy should be (per view):

1) Create the view

2) Set up constraints for each view

3) Animate the constraints for each view, sequentially

Anybody have any suggestions or pointers to helpful tutorials? A simple example relating several code-generated views to each other, particularly inside a `UIScrollView` would be a godsend.

Many thanks!

Comment: You linked to your "my videos" page - everybody's "my videos" page is different.

Comment: I was suspicious of that URL. Know how I can extract one everyone can see?

Comment: I'm uploading the videos to Youtube right now...

Comment: OK, the vids are on youtube via the links in the question...

Comment: Kind of vague. Is the problem that you don't understand how autolayout works inside a scroll view or you don't understand that you can animate a change in constraints?

Comment: @rattletrap99 Just use `NSLayoutConstraint` to set up the constraints?

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness. My real problem is not understanding how to animate a change in constraints, particularly with multiple views whose dimensions are created on the fly.

Comment: Firstly, you will need to declare the `NSLayoutConstraint ` constraint somewhere and then you can modify the `constant` of the constraint whenever you want.

Comment: I suppose it's mainly a matter of unfamiliarity, but I'd love to see a snippet of code that would achieve the effect shown in the video. I'm not asking anyone to do my work for me, but it looks like this is going to require a fundamental rewrite of my animation code, and I would be very grateful for some explicit (even graphical) guidance.

Comment: It's the same as you currently have it (once you've got a reference to the constraint(s))  `[UIView animations:^{ constraint.constant = newValue; }]`

Comment: Thanks @RyanDignard! I'm busily adding constraints in a test app. I must say that this seems much more arcane than simply animating frame attributes.